# Loop objects in array to create element

Tags: javascript

I am creating a comparison between popular javascript frameworks and need to create an HTML element for each object returned from an api.

```
const frameworks = [
  {
    name: "angular"
  },
  {
    name: "ember"
  },
  {
    name: "react"
  },
  {
    name: "vue"
  }
];
```

To keep it simple I just have an array of objects (this is simplified for readability).

I have a function to loop over this array and for now it's just printing the name of the framework to the console. If I want to create this HTML element (just a bootstrap card) for each item in the loop, what would be the best way to do it?

```
frameworks.forEach(fw => {
    console.log(fw);
  });
```

Just a very simple forEach function.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px180/?text=Image cap" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do this in vanilla JS otherwise I would just use React. This just seems a bit cumbersome. Is the best way to do it is to scaffold this as a template with the `createElement()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain javascript :

```
const frameworks = [
  {
    name: "angular"
  },
  {
    name: "ember"
  },
  {
    name: "react"
  },
  {
    name: "vue"
  }
];

frameworks.forEach( framework => {
  const card = `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px180/?text=Image cap" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${framework.name}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>`
  const ele = document.createElement('div');
  ele.innerHTML = card;
  document.body.appendChild(ele.firstChild);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to add any event listeners, I'd suggest `insertAdjacentHTML()`:

```js
const frameworks = [
  {
    name: "angular"
  },
  {
    name: "ember"
  },
  {
    name: "react"
  },
  {
    name: "vue"
  }
];

frameworks.forEach( framework => 
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", 
  `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px180/?text=Image cap" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${framework.name}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>`))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you using `reduce` instead of `forEach`.
Prepare your HTML as a string, then update `innerHTML` of the parent element.
It would be way faster than adding cards one-by-one.

See the snippet below:

```js
const frameworks = [{
    name: "angular"
  },
  {
    name: "ember"
  },
  {
    name: "react"
  },
  {
    name: "vue"
  }
];

document.querySelector('.content')
  .innerHTML = frameworks.reduce((a, fw) => a +=
  `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src=".../100px180/?text=Image cap" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${fw.name}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>`, ''
);
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
  margin: .5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fec
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Hope it helps.